# No matching distribution found for PyJWT<3.0.0,>=2.0.1

Tags: python, pip, ibm-watson, pyjwt

I' trying to install ibm_watson library following the steps from their web:

```
https://cloud.ibm.com/apidocs/assistant/assistant-v1?code=python
```

However I get this error:

```
Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement PyJWT<3.0.0,>=2.0.1 (from ibm_cloud_sdk_core>=3.3.6->ibm-watson) (from versions: 0.1.1, 0.1.2, 0.1.3, 0.1.4, 0.1.5, 0.1.6, 0.1.7, 0.1.8, 0.1.9, 0.2.0, 0.2.1, 0.2.3, 0.3.0, 0.3.1, 0.3.2, 0.4.0, 0.4.1, 0.4.2, 0.4.3, 1.0.0, 1.0.1, 1.1.0, 1.3.0, 1.4.0, 1.4.1, 1.4.2, 1.5.0, 1.5.1, 1.5.2, 1.5.3, 1.6.0, 1.6.1, 1.6.3, 1.6.4, 1.7.0, 1.7.1)
No matching distribution found for PyJWT<3.0.0,>=2.0.1 (from ibm_cloud_sdk_core>=3.3.6->ibm-watson)
```

I tried to manually install PyJWT with version 2.0.1 but I get the same error although that version is available in their documentation.

Does anyone know how to solve this issue?

Comment: Are you on the outdated Python 2?

Comment: No, python version is 3.7.9

Comment: Please check with `pip --version`. If that's not the problem add the output of `pip -v PyJTW==2.0.1`.

Comment: pip 20.3.4 from /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip (python 2.7), i guess this is the problem. How do I update it?

Comment: At first you could try `pip3 --version`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So the problem was that when I executed pip --version, it showed python 2.7 version which is deprecated in PyJWT.
I solved it executing:

```
sudo python3 -m pip install --upgrade --force pip
```

With that, I get python 3.7 version when I execute pip --version.